# Open Source online software for making maps and displaying data?

Tags: open-source-gis, mapping, web, online

I have noticed a number of online maps with data, however I wonder if there are any similar to umap that allows integration of data as in codap and offer features like openwebgis, ideally with an installation guide.

I have seen cartodb however installation seems to be a challenging task.
I need to set it up to show my boss so we can perhaps use it in my organization while not infringing on any licenses.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean installing the system on your own server or just building a small webapplication with those?

If the ones you listed don´t fullfill your needs it will be difficult as they are software as a service and deliver just what they got. I could only add mapbox as an alternative here. But they have the same system as cartodb which means to a certain level they are free and bigger projects need to be paid.

Beside those kind of service providers where you need to rely on the few mostly general tools you can of course create your own webapplications with the classic approach of database/webserver/webclient.